# Assigning values to polygon layer based on nearest point in point layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, proximity, arcgis-9.2

I have a point file depicting groundstations for rainfall measurment. I also have a polygon file representing districts of a state. I want to assign rainfall values in a particular district based on the station located there. I understand this can be achieved through a spatial join. However, I also want to assign these values to near by districts based on a value taken from the nearest station in the surrounding districts.

Please note that

- a single district can theoretically have multiple stations.
- I want to assign the exact value, and not an interpolated value.

I am working on ArcGIS Desktop 9.2.

Comment: Also, please note that the match option "closest" is not available in Spatial Join in ArcMap 9.2

Comment: What match options do you have in 9.2?  If you have within_a_ distance you could play with that to catch most of the districts and then manually complete the outliers.

Comment: ArcGIS 9.2 is a retired version so, in the absence of any activity here in nearly 12 months I have voted for it to be closed as "too localized in time".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154076/spatial-join-geotagged-images-to-preexisting-point-shapefile