# Spatial join geotagged images to preexisting point shapefile?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, nearest-neighbor

I have a layer of geotagged images (points with jpg thumbnail attachment), and another layer of different points (shapefile with various attributes). I would like to perform a spatial operation in which the jpg thumbnail from the geotagged image layer gets added to the attribute table of the closest point in the other layer. I've tried spatial join but I'm not sure that I am doing it correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to download attachments to disk and re-attach them to feature class in geodatabase. Make sure attachments enabled on it

Comment: Which of the two desktop GIS products are you actually using to try and do this?  By having tags for both in the same question you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spatial join in QGIS seems to have a problem when joining 2 point geometries. A plug-in called *NNJoin* can handle any geometry combinations and can perform a join on nearest neighbour rather than on intersection.

It doesn't offer any options for choosing which attributes to join however, so you may have to manually delete some columns if you only want the one column

Answer (score 0):

One option would be in ArcGIS to first use the [GeoTagged Photos To Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000165000000) tool and then use the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) tool (defining a search radius).